# VBA referring to item in for loop

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have a quick for loop for a named range:

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each itm In Range("List")
itm.Value = "fish"
next itm
```

Works fine. But If I were to change the third line to

```
itm.Offset(0,1).Value = "fish"
```

Then there is a problem since itm isn't a range (i think). Is there a way to refer to the range of itm, or set up a for loop to refer to the cells/ranges rather than the value of itm. (and why does the original one work?)

Comment: works for me. what is the problem?

Comment: Try `Range("List").Cells` then... sometimes you need to add this to show that you want to go for each cell

Comment: @dirk reichel This fixed it, thanks. Realized after that some were working and some weren't so it was something else other than I originally thought. But using Range("list") seems to make it realize you were going for a cell so it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly declare itm as Range

```
Dim itm as Range
```

Then your `for..each` block will return each cell as a range

P.S. If you just want to set all of the cells to `fish` then you could use these lines, and avoid the loop altogether:

```
Range("List").Value = "fish"
```

or

```
Range("List").Offset(0,1).Value = "fish"
```